# Having a generator expression as an input argument in Python

Tags: python-2.7, function, input, generator-expression

How can I interact with the values of a generator expression? For instance:

```
def sumValues(*args):
# compute the sum of values

sumValues(abs(x) for x in range(0,10))
```

When the range is known (e.g., we know the range is [0,10)), we can put a for loop, but what if the range is unknown?

Comment: for this case you can also use the build-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid using any of the built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depend on how you want your function to be called, if you want to call it with list, generator, or more generally a iterable (anything that can be used in a for-loop) and imitate the behavior of the build-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) then

```
def my_sum(iterable):
    total = 0
    for x in iterable:
        total += x
    return total
```

and use like

```
my_sum(range(10))
my_sum(abs(x) for x in range(0,10))
my_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

if you want to imitate the behavior of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and use it as above and also like `my_sum(1,2)`, `my_sum(1,2,3)`, `my_sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`, etc. then

```
def my_sum(*argv):
    total = 0
    values = None
    if len(argv) == 1:
        values = argv[0]
    else:
        values = argv
    for x in values:
        total += x
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured. Here's the answer:

```
def sumValues(*args):
    # compute the sum of values
    total = 0
    for item in args[0]:
        total += item
    return total

print(sumValues(abs(x) for x in range(0,10)))
[output] => 45
```